# What is the the fastest algorithm in DNA pattern matching

Tags: c++, algorithm, pattern-matching

Suppose we have a string S with a length of several millions. The string only contains 'a' 't' 'g' 'c' and we have a pattern W with a length of roughly 20. What could be the fastest algorithm in C++ to find ALL occurrences of W in S? It seems KMP is not fast enough.

Comment: Go wide... run multiple threads pattern matching via KMP each on a section of the string. Beyond that, go _really_ wide via CUDA/OpenCl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) although, if you are only processing it once, the tree takes O(n log n) to create, so KMP is faster for single checkings. So if you have multiple distinct 'W's to find then I would go with a Suffix Tree, else KMP is probably your best bet.

From the wikipedia article:

> The suffix array of a string can be used as an index to quickly locate
>   every occurrence of a substring pattern P within the string S. Finding
>   every occurrence of the pattern is equivalent to finding every suffix
>   that begins with the substring. Thanks to the lexicographical
>   ordering, these suffixes will be grouped together in the suffix array
>   and can be found efficiently with two binary searches.

Comment: @aaronman: Read the answer again: "So if you have multiple 'W's..."

Comment: @DietrichEpp my mistake, he should say multiple different W's though

Comment: @aaronman Your probably right, updated to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Building a suffix array costs O(n log n) but n here is about 9,000,000. So how many W's do you think will be enough for the benefit to outweigh the cost?

Comment: @smilingdays That depends on a lot of things to do with the actual Strings in question, but off the top of my head, I'd probably do with thousands.

Answer (score 3):

KMP is linear in S+W. You can't get faster than that.

You at least need to read the data, and that is also linear. So even if your algorithm is instant, you still can't do much better than KMP.

I suspect you do something wrong reading the data or traversing it in a way that destroys caching.